# Filter/Search A Table Using Partial Match - HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have an HTML table which I am trying to filter using fuzzy search and partial matches. I have tried many JS libraries, but they don't seem to offer both of these filter options combined. I have tried FuzySort.js, FlexSearch.js, and others. Does anyone know of a library that can do this?

**The foundation:**

- MySQL stores the data.
- Front end displays the table.
- Admins have a separate front-end lets them add/remove/edit the data to MySQL.
- JavaScript to filter/sort/search the table client side on the front end.

**Requirements:**

- Full text search
- Fuzzy search
- Partial matches.

**Expected Results:**
If...

- Table row #1 has the name "Name1"
- Table row #2 has the name "Name2"
- Table row #3 has the name "Name3"
- And in the search bar, you type "Name1 Name3" it should display row 1 and 3

**Current Results:**

- in the search bar, when you type "Name1 Name3" it displays no results.

**Current Code**

```
    function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

**Here is my JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/h7p8bzs0/

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.
Does anyone have any suggestions for what library can achieve these results, or how I can tweak the JS code above to do this?

Ps: Sorry, I'm new and overwhelmed with the options of using JSON, Node.JS, Actual Databases, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to try the following Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const filters = input.value.toUpperCase().split(' '); // create several filters separated by space
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    const td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

    if (td) {
      const txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        tr[i].style.display = "none"; // hide each row
        
      for (filter of filters) { // add the rows matching a filter
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";        
        }
      }       
    }
  }
}
```

What happens here is that we create more than one filter string to match against, separated by a space. We hide each row as soon as we have at least one filter and add it again if it matches at least one of the filters.

Oh and I restructered your variables a bit: We don't need declarators beforehand and we want to have them as let or const so that they aren't global.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thank you for taking the time to make these edits. I had no idea that JS without a library could achieve this so easily. Is there a way to also have it ignore keywords that are not found in the search? Example if I were to search "Name1 Name2 Dog" would it be able to exclude/ignore "Dog" from the filter search since its not found in the table? If filter1 != tr use filter2. If filter2 != tr use filter 3.

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand what you want to say. 
The filter as I wrote it already ignores filters which don't match - so in your example "Name1 Name2 Dog" the rows for name1 and name2 get displayed and dog does not do anything.